# Instructions for mounting multiple iSCSI volumes on Softlayer VSI CentOS 6

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, iscsi

I've got a grasp on mounting a single iSCSI "endurance" block storage volume, on a Softlayer VSI, under Linux, CentOS 6...   however, wondering if there are instructions available for being able to mount multiple, different volumes of the same type, at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to mount multiple iSCSI devices to a VM ata same time, when you are mounting all the available iSCSI devices should be displayed.

You can follow this instructions

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/accessing-block-storage-linux

https://softlayerslayers.wordpress.com/storage/endurance-storage-overview/

Regards